# IndexedDB composite index partial match

Tags: indexing, indexeddb, partial, composite

I can't find an answer to this anywhere.

I have an indexeddb composite index of a group id and a time, which I use to sort.

let tmp_CREATEDTIMEindex = texts.index('GROUP_ID, CREATEDTIME');

This works great, except I need to result to reflect only the group id, not the time.  How do I get a result from a match on just the group id?

To clarify, this returns one record:
let request = tmp_CREATEDTIMEindex.getAll(['someid', 'August, 25 2022 06:52:02']);

I need it to return all records.
let request = tmp_CREATEDTIMEindex.getAll(['someid', '*']);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a key range:

```
let range = IDBKeyRange.bound(['someid'], ['someid\x00'], true, true);
let request = tmp_CREATEDTIMEindex.getAll(range);
```

- `['someid']` sorts before any other composite key starting with 'someid'
- `['someid\x00']` sorts after any other composite key starting with 'someid'
- the `true, true` arguments exclude those keys specifically from the results

Comment: Joshua Bell genius, many thanks!  Works perfectly!